# Three Column Population

Tags: php, sql

So, I took over a project from someone else, and I am trying to populate three columns in a table where there was previously two columns. I've almost got things figured out, but can't quite get my third column to fill. I've got it so its separating the the data into thirds, but only the left column actually has exactly one third of the data. The middle column has the other two thirds of data, and the right column has no data.

Here is the code I am working with. However, I've changed what we produce to "stuff" and left out the url for privacy reasons:

```
    $iUp = 1;

    $pQuery = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $pExist = mysql_num_rows($pQuery);

    if(!empty($pExist)){

        //$this->stuffPackageOut .= '<form action="https://*************.111/cart" method="GET" name="stuff" onsubmit="return anyCheck()">';
        //$this->stuffPackageOut .= '<form action="index.php" method="GET" name="stuff" onsubmit="return anyCheck()">';
        $this->stuffPackageOut .= '<input type="hidden" name="cart!addFamily">';

        $pCnt = $pExist;
        $pCntHalf = floor($pCnt/3);
        $stuff[0] = NULL;
        $stuff[1] = NULL;
        $stuff[2] = NULL;
        $div = 0;

        while($pRow = mysql_fetch_object($pQuery)){
            if($pCntHalf < $iUp){
                $div = 2;
                $div = 1;
            }else{
                $div = 0;

            }

            $contribName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $pRow->conName));
            $stuffName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $pRow->stfName));

            $stuff[$div] .= '<tr><td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="cart_family'.$iUp.'" value="'.$pRow->familyId.'" id="package"> <a href="http://****************.com/stuff/'.$stuffName.'.php" class="packagestufflinks">'.$pRow->fntName.'</td></tr>';
            $iUp++;
        }

        $stuffLeft  = '<table width="137" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" height="10" valign="top">';
        $stuffLeft .= $stuff[0];
        $stuffLeft .= '</table>';

        $stuffMiddle  = '<table width="137" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" height="10" valign="top">';
        $stuffMiddle .= $stuff[1];
        $stuffMiddle .= '</table>';

        $stuffRight  = '<table width="137" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" height="10" valign="top">';
        $stuffRight .= $stuff[2];
        $stuffRight .= '</table>';

        $this->stuffPackageOut .= '<table width="100%" height="10"><tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="238" height="10">'.$stuffLeft.'</td><td width="29" valign="top" background="verticaldivider.gif"><img src="http://www.****************.com/pageimages/spacer.GIF" width="29" height="5"></td><td align="left" valign="top" width="238">'.$stuffMiddle.'<td><td width="29" valign="top" background="verticaldivider.gif"><img src="http://www.****************.com/pageimages/spacer.GIF" width="29" height="5"></td><td align="left" valign="top" width="238">'.$stuffRight.'</td></tr></table>';
```

I know it has something to do with everything following the "while" coding, but since I don't do this for a living I have no idea what coding is necessary to make my three columns populate.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... it should work for you... used this logic before and worked well:

```
<?php

   $iUp = 1;

    $pQuery = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $pExist = mysql_num_rows($pQuery);

    if(!empty($pExist)){

        $this->stuffPackageOut .= '<input type="hidden" name="cart!addFamily">';

        $pCnt = $pExist;
        $pCntHalf = floor($pCnt/3);


        while($pRow = mysql_fetch_object($pQuery)){
            $contribName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $pRow->conName));
            $stuffName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $pRow->stfName));

            if($iUp <= $pCntHalf){
            $stuff_left_a .= '<tr><td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="cart_family'.$iUp.'" value="'.$pRow->familyId.'" id="package"> <a href="http://****************.com/stuff/'.$stuffName.'.php" class="packagestufflinks">'.$pRow->fntName.'</td></tr>';          
            }
            elseif($iUp >= $pCntHalf +1 && $iUp <= ($pCntHalf * 2)){
            $stuff_middle_a .= '<tr><td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="cart_family'.$iUp.'" value="'.$pRow->familyId.'" id="package"> <a href="http://****************.com/stuff/'.$stuffName.'.php" class="packagestufflinks">'.$pRow->fntName.'</td></tr>';
            }
            elseif($iUp >= ($pCntHalf *2) +1){
            $stuff_right_a .= '<tr><td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="cart_family'.$iUp.'" value="'.$pRow->familyId.'" id="package"> <a href="http://****************.com/stuff/'.$stuffName.'.php" class="packagestufflinks">'.$pRow->fntName.'</td></tr>';
            }            
            $iUp++;
        }

        $stuffLeft  = '<table width="137" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" height="10" valign="top">';
        $stuffLeft .= $stuff_left_a;
        $stuffLeft .= '</table>';

        $stuffMiddle  = '<table width="137" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" height="10" valign="top">';
        $stuffMiddle .= $stuff_middle_a;
        $stuffMiddle .= '</table>';

        $stuffRight  = '<table width="137" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" height="10" valign="top">';
        $stuffRight .= $stuff_right_a;
        $stuffRight .= '</table>';

        $this->stuffPackageOut .= '<table width="100%" height="10">
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="238" height="10">'.$stuffLeft.'</td>

        <td width="29" valign="top" background="verticaldivider.gif">
        <img src="http://www.****************.com/pageimages/spacer.GIF" width="29" height="5">
        </td>

        <td align="left" valign="top" width="238">'.$stuffMiddle.'<td>

        <td width="29" valign="top" background="verticaldivider.gif">
        <img src="http://www.****************.com/pageimages/spacer.GIF" width="29" height="5">
        </td>

        <td align="left" valign="top" width="238">'.$stuffRight.'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>';

?>
```

I found the error... it was in my math in the middle... notice the change:

```
elseif($iUp >= $pCntHalf +1 && $iUp <= ($pCntHalf * 2))
```

Comment: Thanks petebolduc. I'm almost there. The left and right columns are populated, but the middle column only has one "stuff" item in it. What could be causing that?

Comment: i just came back on... let me look

Comment: I found the error and edited my previous post... sorry about that guy was rushing through it yesterday. Also I took out the unneeded code

Comment: your welcome... glad it worked for you... have used that logic numerous times